# Wireless energy flow through earths magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

Seeing that technologies such as that developed by [WItricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiTricity) are based on magnetic fields, is it possible to transfer electricity that way through earths magnetic field?

Answer (score 2):

Witricity uses a rapidly [changing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power) magnetic field to induce a current in a receiver (coil). This is based on Faraday's law of induction:
$$U = - \frac{d}{dt} \int  \vec B \cdot d\vec A$$
From this you see that a *changing* magnetic field is necessary.

[image]

The Earth's magnetic field, however, is largely static (compass!) and certainly not fast enough to induce a measurable current in such a receiver.

[image]